# labeling lines value in countour plot using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to learn how to use ggplot2, and I get stack in countour plots. I manage to get a nice countour plot with a colour scale, but I have not found anywhere how can I put the value of some of the lines in the plot.

My code is:

```
rm(list=ls())
#Create data in a regular grid with a symple function to easyly check
x <- 1:100
y <- 1:100
data <- data.frame(1:(100*100))
data[,1]<-x
for(i in x){
    data[(i*100-100+1):(i*100),2]<-y[i]
}
fun <- function(x,y){return(exp(((x-50)/100)**(2) + ((y-50)/100)**2))}

data[,3]<-fun(data[,1],data[,2])
colnames(data)<-c('x','y','z')

#Plot
a<-ggplot(data=data, aes(x = x, y = y,z=z))
a + geom_contour(aes(x=x, y=y, colour=..level..)) + scale_color_gradient(low='blue', high='red')
```

This create a countour plot with colour gradient as I wish, but I do not know how to add a the value of some or all of the countour lines with a number in the graphic. Like this plot for exsample:
https://www.curveexpert.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/contour_sample_lines.png